# Microsoft Graph : Daemon App Accesses Shared Calendars of only One User

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

My scenario:

- I want users to be able to share *some* of their calendars with a daemon app.
- I want the daemon app. to have readWrite access *only* to these shared calendars.

The idea is that users can "opt-in" to a service simply by creating a calendar and sharing it with the daemon and then unsharing it to opt out.  I want to avoid having to involve administrative staff to manage permissions.  I also want to avoid having to make some program for managing the permissions.  And the sharing part makes it easy for my daemon to find which calendars it has to work with.

My solution:

1. Create a service account with e-mails and calendars.  Users share the calendars they want with this account.
2. Create an app account with Calendar and e-mail rights.
3. Create a Security Group with e-mail access and add the service account to this group.
4. use the *New-ApplicationAccessPolicy PowerShell cmdlet* to restrict the app to have access only to the security group.

The problem is that this cmdlet doesn't seem to understand shared calendars.  In the list of *Supported permissions and additional resources* it doesn't mention shared calendars.  (I will be trying this as soon as I can but I suspect it will fail)

Is there some way around this limitation?  This question seems similar to other questions where the app. should "ActAs" a specific user and the other answers were generally "can't do it."

[New-ApplicationAccessPolicy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)

[Mail-Enabled-Security-Group documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-mail-enabled-security-groups)

The solution must use Java.

Comment: Seems like "can't do it" will be the final answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http your app would need `Calendar.Read` / `Calendar.ReadWrite`. and you can only restricted it to a specific user, not a specific calendar.

Comment: @Stephan but I *do* want to restrict it to one user, but the access should include the calendars other people have shared with this one user.  (maybe my question is badly phrased?)

Answer (score 0):

New-ApplicationAccessPolicy is intended to restrict app-only access to specific mailboxes.

In your scenario, you should be able to use Delegated Permissions in the context of the service account, which is already restricted in the mailboxes it can read.

The device code flow should work. Or use KeyVault (or an equivalent) to store the credentials of the service account and use the ROPC flow.